# performance difference between platforms

Tags: java, programming-languages

This is more of a general programming questions about a GIANT performance issue I have seen..

Basically I'll use two common programs for an example - Eclipse IDE & Newsbin (usenet client)

On my Windows 7 Machine, Eclipse is so sluggish it's almost painful to use and this is built on the java platform right?

Whilst Newsbin, on the same machine, can handle hundreds of thousands of header information and literally NEVER lags.. It's one of the most responsive programmed I have ever used..

So, is there any chance someone could shed some light on which language/platform Newsbin is built upon? I'm curious because I want to expand my skills into desktop applications and there seems to be such a massive difference in performance.

Apologies if this type of question shouldn't be posted here, but it is 'linked' with programming and I would very much like some feedback/answers.

Thanks.

Comment: try assigning more memory to Eclipse and see if the performance improves

Comment: What does Eclipse have to do with Newsbin?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reason the performance could be different.  It is most likely a tuning problem or you hardware doesn't suit the application.  I use IntelliJ CE (another IDE like Eclipse) and it caches a lot of information about the Java classes it uses. It does this to provide rich refactoring/search capabilities.  This can result in enormous amounts of disk activity if you don't have lots of free memory (to cache the disk data).  I use a machine with 48 GB of memory and it almost never lags (at least not when I am the only one using it)

My guess is that newsbin of keeps the most essential information about each post and avoids having to cache lots of information about each article. i.e. its has a completely different use and usage pattern.

Comment: Could you point me in the correct direction for me to re-post?

Comment: @dantuch, I got sick of people closing questions before I can answer meaning my time was wasted. So instead I added a place holder answer I could change later. ;)

Comment: Ah, good practice ;p anyway - you have 48GB of RAM? :O

Comment: Its there so I may as well use it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The performance between the two is most likely not the platform but the fact that the two are very different application.

Second, two version of the same program can be vastly different. You can create a slower Newsbin type application in the same platform that your Newsbin's application uses.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples to oranges: these two programs do completely different things and the performance difference probably has nothing to do with the underlying platform or language.

Also, keep in mind that Eclipse can be fast by itself, but you can ad plugins to it, and poorly written plugins can slow it down horrendously.

Remember: no matter what language you're using, you can always find a way to write code that is poor enough to make a program feel slow and unresponsive.